# Elapsed Time in Access using record above

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, macros

```
    M   Qty TStamp  DStamp
VF6 1   11:34:38 AM 8/11/2016 11:34:38 AM
VF6 1   1:06:01 PM  8/11/2016 1:06:01 PM
VF6 1   2:16:30 PM  8/11/2016 2:16:30 PM
VF6 1   3:30:20 PM  8/11/2016 3:30:20 PM
VF6 1   4:03:48 PM  8/11/2016 4:03:48 PM
VF6 1   4:52:23 PM  8/11/2016 4:52:23 PM
VF6 1   11:06:31 PM 8/11/2016 11:06:31 PM
VF6 1   12:23:23 AM 8/12/2016 12:23:23 AM
VF6 1   1:23:26 AM  8/12/2016 1:23:26 AM
VF6 1   2:43:20 AM  8/12/2016 2:43:20 AM
VF6 1   3:40:12 AM  8/12/2016 3:40:12 AM
VF6 1   4:40:09 AM  8/12/2016 4:40:09 AM
VF6 1   5:38:44 AM  8/12/2016 5:38:44 AM
VF6 1   6:52:05 AM  8/12/2016 6:52:05 AM
VF6 1   8:00:43 AM  8/12/2016 8:00:43 AM
```

Above is some sample data.
I am wanting to get the elapsed times between records. For example I would like to know the elapsed time from:

```
11:34:38 AM and 1:06:01 PM
```

It's fairly simple if the fields are in the same record, but i am having difficulties using above information to generate the elapsed time. Any guidance will be a big help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In other DBMS systems, retrieving values from either the previous row or the next row is accomplished via `LAG` or `LEAD` functions. Access does not support those functions, but you can accomplish the same thing using subqueries. See the sample SQL below, in which I have assumed that the name of your table is "TableName".

You didn't mention the unit in which you would like to display the elapsed time, or whether each row should be compared to the previous row or the next row. So here, both comparisons are done, and elapsed time is displayed in seconds.

```
SELECT t.M
     , t.[Qty TStamp]
     , t.DStamp
     , (SELECT TOP 1 t1.DStamp
        FROM TableName t1 
        WHERE t1.DStamp < t.DStamp
        ORDER BY t1.DStamp DESC
       ) AS PreviousDStamp
     , (SELECT TOP 1 t2.DStamp
        FROM TableName t2
        WHERE t2.DStamp > t.DStamp
        ORDER BY t2.DStamp
       ) AS NextDStamp
      , DateDiff("s", PreviousDStamp, t.DStamp) AS Seconds_From_Previous
      , DateDiff("s", t.DStamp, NextDStamp) AS Seconds_To_Next
FROM TableName t
ORDER BY t.DStamp
;
```

Please note that even though your question mentioned comparing only the time values, this SQL actually compares the full date/time values (i.e. the `DStamp` column). This way, your data will be accurate even if the date changes between rows.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that difficult:

```
Select *,
    (Select Max(T.DStamp)
    From YourTable As T
    Where T.DStamp < YourTable.DStamp) As LastDStamp
From YourTable
```

or the other way around:

```
Select *,
    (Select Min(T.DStamp)
    From YourTable As T
    Where T.DStamp > YourTable.DStamp) As NextDStamp
From YourTable
```

If you need the timepart only:

```
Select *,
    (Select TimeValue(Max(T.DStamp))
    From YourTable As T
    Where T.DStamp < YourTable.DStamp) As LastTStamp
From YourTable
```